# Blackberry - HttpConnection response code return as 301 instead of 200 in simulator

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

The following code is working fine on device, but in simulator i am getting response as 301 instead of 200. Anybody have an idea why its like this and how to fix this?

```
 ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
 factory.setConnectionTimeout(10000);

 ConnectionDescriptor connDesc = factory.getConnection("http://google.com");

 if (connDesc != null)
 {               
       HttpConnection con = (HttpConnection)connDesc.getConnection();
       System.out.println("Response code "+con.getResponseCode();                        
       int statusCode = con.getResponseCode();
       if (statusCode == HttpConnection.HTTP_OK)
       {
            System.out.println("connected");
       }
 }
```

The above code why it return the response as 301 instead of 200.

Thanks

Comment: Anyone considering responding may wish to review the responses given to the similar question here: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Blackberry-HttpConnection-response-code-return-as-301-in/td-p/2795637

Comment: try with www.google.com